# Different results when release applications

Tags: java, android

I'm making a keyboard application with Telex typing and having a rather silly error that can't be explained, can someone explain this problem to help me? It only happens when release (generate apk) application, when running debug it runs normally without any difference.

```
int value = (originalTypedChar == 'w' ? 'ư' : 'Ư');
handleCharacterWhileInBatchEdit(value);
```

function check log

```
private void handleCharacterWhileInBatchEdit(final int primaryCode) {
    Log.e("TAG", "primaryCode: " + primaryCode);
}
```

result log: primaryCode: 119 (if originalTypedChar == 'w' is true) or 87 (if originalTypedChar == 'w' is false) but not 432(if true) or 431(if false)

when I insert a line Log like this, the result is correct:

```
int value = (originalTypedChar == 'w' ? 'ư' : 'Ư');
Log.e("TAG", "value : " + value);
handleCharacterWhileInBatchEdit(value);
```

result log: 432 (if true) or 431 (if false)

ASCII code 'w' is 119,
ASCII code 'W' is 97,
ASCII code 'ư' is 432,
ASCII code 'Ư' is 431.